# Parse different elements from single class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Background: I'm fairly experienced with Python but a total noob with BeautifulSoup

I'm trying to get 3 values from a single class. The page I'm working with looks has a series of elements that look like this:

```
<blockquote>
<a name="title"><p><B>Title</b> <table frame="hsides" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" bordercolor="darkblue"><tr><td><font face="arial" size="2" color="#0000CC"><b><I>Subtitle</I>: Top Text.</b></font></td></tr></table> Body Text.
<a name="title2".... etc
</blockquote>
```

Currently, I'm simply dumping all the text into a list like this:

```
page_html = soup(page, 'html.parser')

text = []
for a in page_html.select('a'):
    text.append(a.text)
```

And this returns a result where each row looks like:

```
Title Subtitle: Top Text. Body Text.
```

What I'd really like is to be able to parse each `a` into a row in a dataframe that looks something like:

```
col1      col2                    col3
Title     Subtitle: Top Text.     Body Text.
```

But I'm frankly in a little bit over my head.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's what the page looks like? The entire content is within a single link/anchor element (`<a>`)? And the content is all within that paragraph?

Comment: Sorry if that's unclear, just edited a bit. There is other stuff on the page too but the part that I'm interested in are the `<a>` tags. But yes I just copied the html from the page and filled in some placeholder text

Comment: So, looking into this further, your skepticism is well placed. This page I'm trying to scrape is made very poorly. The `<a>` tags are not closed and are instead nested within each other :(

Comment: If the page isn't overly large, you could consider using another strategy, like regex, to search the text for the relevant patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your all `<a>` tags are same , you can use this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd


page = '''<blockquote>
<a name="title"><p><B>Title</b> <table frame="hsides" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" bordercolor="darkblue"><tr><td><font face="arial" size="2" color="#0000CC"><b><I>Subtitle</I>: Top Text.</b></font></td></tr></table> Body Text.</blockquote>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")



text = []


for texts in soup.find_all('a'):
    paragraph = texts.find('p')

    title = texts.find('b').text
    subtitle = texts.find_all('b')[1].text
    other = ''.join(paragraph.find_all(text=True, recursive=False))

    d = {'col1': [title], 'col2': [subtitle],'col3' : [other]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


print(df)
```

OUTPUT :

```
   col1                 col2          col3
0  Title  Subtitle: Top Text.    Body Text.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just the segment of HTML you shared:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '<a name="title"><p><B>Title</b> ' \
          '<table frame="hsides" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" bordercolor="darkblue">' \
          '<tr><td><font face="arial" size="2" color="#0000CC"><b><I>Subtitle</I>: Top Text.</b></font>' \
          '</td></tr></table> Body Text.'

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
articles = soup.find_all('a')

for article in articles:
    paragraph = article.find('p')
    print({
        'title': article.find('b').text,
        'subtitle': article.select('table i')[0].text,
        'body': ''.join(paragraph.find_all(text=True, recursive=False))
    })
```

Since the question is primarily about BeautifulSoup, not so much about Pandas, I figured a dictionary should be enough and you can get it into a dataframe or other data structure yourself?

Result:

```
{'title': 'Title', 'subtitle': 'Subtitle', 'body': '  Body Text.'}
```